# Within __asm__, what does "$variable" mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

```
int context(){"\
       movl $0, %eax;\
       push $xxxxx;\
       push $0;\
       push %eax;\
       ...........
       xxxxx : leave;\
       ret;");
}
```

I'm very beginner.

At above source code, I couldn't understand the meaning of "$xxxxx".
I thought symbol '$' is only come front of constant.

Moreover, I have never seen last two lines.
I know about leave and ret instruction, but "xxxxx :" form is so unfamiliar.
I can't find the example looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` prefix signals an immediate operand in the GNU assembler's AT&T syntax. See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html#i386_002dVariations:

> AT&T immediate operands are preceded by '$';

The line:

```
xxxxx : leave;
```

uses `xxxxx` as a label (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Labels.html#Labels).

> A label is written as a symbol immediately followed by a colon `:'

In the case you're wondering about, the value of the label `xxxxx` is the immediate operand.

Comment: A label is just a name for a location - a memory address basically.  An immediate operand is data that gets encoded into the instruction opcode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I'm afraid I couldn't understand the mechanism of immediate operand and label. 
This is what I understand ----> At line "push $xxxxx", program counter jumps to label "xxxxx :" and precede(like a call instruction). And return to the caller by instruction "ret". Then what value is pushed to stack at line "push $xxxxx" ?? (If you hard to understand my comment, I'm sorry. I'm not good at English.)

Comment: Lets say that the label `xxxxx` has the value `0x1234`.  Then `push $xxxxx` will push the value `0x1234` onto the stack. That instruction doesn't transfer control or jump anywhere - it just pushes the value of the address represented by `xxxxx` onto the stack.  The code snippet you posted doesn't show what is done with that value on the stack.  It's possible that some subsequent instruction will `ret` with that value in place on the stack to act as a return address, in effect jumping to it, but that isn't in the code you have posted.

Comment: Oh! I understand what you mean. '$xxxxx' is just equal to memory address of instruction 'xxxxx : leave'. Thank you very much!!